# What is the meaning of "backslash"

Tags: meaning, nouns, slang

I have seen several people use the word *backslash*, it sounds like something similar to disaster, bad result, etc. But I am not quite sure what it means and when I should use it.

Examples:

> - But if big layoffs result at home, corporations and the US government will face a backslash.
> - Celeb Boutique saw a major backslash as result after the inappropriate usage of the word *Aurora*.

Comment: The word is backlash. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/backlash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not slang, and the word you want is almost certainly [backlash](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/backlash?q=backlash):

> a strong negative reaction by a large number of people, especially to a social or political development: *a public backlash against racism*

By contrast, Oxford Dictionaries define a [backslash](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/backslash?q=backslash) as

> a backward-sloping diagonal line (\), used in some computer commands.

(In MS Windows Character Map utility, this character is described as a *Reverse Solidus*.)

Comment: ‘Reverse solidus’ is the Unicode name. ‘Backslash’ is a more common and colloquial term. Technically, of course, ‘reverse solidus’ is a misnomer, since the character is a reserved _slash_, not a reversed solidus. But that’s its name.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it's not really a misnomer, as the slash symbol has been called a *solidus* for a long time - mostly when used to stand for *solidus* in currency amounts, but also in other uses - so it is perfectly correct that *solidus* be one of its names, and it is convenient to differentiate it from other similar characters with more specific uses (like fraction and division slashes). As such, it follows that it is perfectly correct for *reverse solidus* to be one of the names for the backslash.

Comment: @JonHanna, I see that the Unicode name for the forward slash has changed. It used to be that ‘solidus’ referred to the fraction slash specifically, and ‘slash’ to `U+002F`, which is apparently now officially known as ‘solidus’. That makes the Unicode nomenclature consistent again, which is what I thought it wasn’t.